# Swagger UI getting 403 (openapi v3)

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui, swagger-3.0

I'm using springdoc-openapi-ui for API documentation

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.14</version>
</dependency>
```

And, following Spring Boot security config.

```
.
.
public static String[] SWAGGER_WHITELIST = {
        "/api-docs",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/webjars/**",
        "/swagger.json"
};
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().disable();
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(SWAGGER_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()

        .and()
            .addFilterAt(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(userService, jwtService, authenticationProvider()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
//            .addFilterAfter(new UserAuthorizationFilter(), JWTAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        return http.build();
    }
.
.
```

Spring boot parent version: 3

When I try to access http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html I'm getting 403.

Anyone facing similar issue? What could be the issue?

I tried

- Whitelisting the swagger URLs
- Changing the swagger doc path from config

I'm getting

- No luck in debugging as console doesn't show any exception
- It just rejects requests without printing any log

Answer (score 0):

### Following changes fixed the issue for me

- Changed from springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.14 to springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2 as it supports spring boot v3.
- Added following things to whitelist

```
public static String[] SWAGGER_WHITELIST = {
            "/api-docs/**",
            "/api-docs.yaml",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
    };
```

- New .properties file (match with whitelist)

```
#Swagger
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
```